# iOS FB Request Dialogs not working properly?

Tags: ios, apprequests, facebook-ios-sdk

We are using the latest fb iOS sdk and for a while we where able to send game invites to our friends and the notification would show up on the users facebook web account.

Over the last few weeks we have been trying to figure out why the request doesnt show up to the user who is invited anymore, for a while we could watch the request pop up for a second on the web page then disappear.

we are using this code

```
    NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                           @"Come check out my app.",  @"message",
                           nil];

[facebook dialog:@"apprequests"
              andParams:params
            andDelegate:self];
```

From the https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/#graph but cannot debug or figure out why it stopped working.

Any thoughts or anyone else seeing this same result?

Comment: Anyone else experiencing this problem?

Answer (score 3):

,Please make sure you have registered you App as "App On Facbook" within your FB app settings.And your Facebook App needs to have a Canvas URL defined. The URL doesn't even need to be valid, it just needs to be defined in the Settings of the App. I have done things in same way and i am getting the Notification of App request in my Facebook Notifications,I hope you can get The App Request Notification in your Facebook Notification.

Answer (score 1):

There is some issue with notifications on apprequest. The user gets the apprequest though but only if he opens the appcenter. Notifications is an issue right now and we're working to get it fixed. Thanks!

Comment: Yes this should be fixed definitively!